# Canvas not update even I called invalidate()?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I want to create a custom view that animates some lines. so I created a class that extends `View` class. I called `onDraw()` & drawn on the canvas.
Here are some codes that I've approached so far.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    p += 10;
    canvas.drawLine(5, 5, p, 5, mPaint);
    invalidate();
}
```

note that p & mPaint are instantiated at the constructor.

but, even I called `invalidate()` method, it doesn't update the canvas, i.e. doesn't animate the line.

so, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not drawing? What colour is your Paint object?

I created a blank 4.4 android application, added this class:

```
package ca.kieve.playground;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class AnimView extends View {
    private int p = 0;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public AnimView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public AnimView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        p += 1;
        canvas.drawLine(5, 5, p, 5, mPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

and changed the activity_main.xml to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ca.kieve.playground.MainActivity" >

    <ca.kieve.playground.AnimView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This draws with no issues.

Comment: just one question, is it possible to have a problem when I instantiate the variable p as a local variable?

Comment: I don't think so. Is it drawing any line at all? You have p+=10. This means every frame it's going to be 10 pixels longer. Within 1 second it will be 600 pixels wide (at 60 fps).

Comment: ok, I have used your code & it seems to be work fine. i'll check what is the wrong on my code.

Answer (score -1):

remove

```
invalidate() form onDraw().
```

use

```
inavalidate() while you have done with your changes.
```

Comment: I really want call invalidate() method, because it forces to redraw on the canvas. that means it creates a loop of onDraw() and each time I have changed the value ofof p, it changes the coordinates of the line, causes an animation.